# How to get video to autoplay on older iPhones?

Tags: ios, iphone, video, iphone-5, autoplay

I know webkit's `playsinline` became part of the toolkit recently, and that the rules on autoplaying on devices have been relaxed. But for some reason, my office has been unable to get a background video to autoplay on iPhone 5 only: iPhone 6s and 7s seem fine, and we haven't tested Android yet.

If you use `playsinline`, no play button with a slash through it comes up, as it does if you do NOT use it. It just won't display.

Any ideas as to how one might fix it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Are they running the same iOS version? If so, what is it?

Comment: They are! 10.3.3